# node.js не устанавливается xpc-connection

Tags: windows, ubuntu, node.js, bluetooth

Не могу установить xpc-connection(https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-xpc-connection) как на винде так и на убунте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с этим бороться?

**UBUNTU:**

[image: ubuntu screen]

```
wsl_f@Wasyl-Y50:/usr/src/noble/noble$ npm install xpc-connection
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "xpc-connection"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: xpc-connection@0.1.4
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "xpc-connection"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.2656069623
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.2656069623'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.2656069623']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.2656069623' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/noble/noble/npm-debug.log
```

log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'xpc-connection' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v4.2.6
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData xpc-connection@~0.1.4
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData xpc-connection
9 silly mapToRegistry name xpc-connection
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection
13 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection
14 verbose request no auth needed
15 info attempt registry request try #1 at 3:49:31
16 verbose request id 36210a918bcc02b1
17 verbose etag "D7L5PUPWDQU3I72FED6TBUILY"
18 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection
19 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection
20 verbose headers { date: 'Mon, 12 Sep 2016 00:49:31 GMT',
20 verbose headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
20 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
20 verbose headers   etag: '"D7L5PUPWDQU3I72FED6TBUILY"',
20 verbose headers   age: '50',
20 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
20 verbose headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1224-FRA',
20 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
20 verbose headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
20 verbose headers   'x-timer': 'S1473641371.788318,VS0,VE0',
20 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
21 silly get cb [ 304,
21 silly get   { date: 'Mon, 12 Sep 2016 00:49:31 GMT',
21 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
21 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
21 silly get     etag: '"D7L5PUPWDQU3I72FED6TBUILY"',
21 silly get     age: '50',
21 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
21 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1224-FRA',
21 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
21 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
21 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1473641371.788318,VS0,VE0',
21 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding' } ]
22 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection from cache
23 verbose get saving xpc-connection to /home/wsl_f/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection/.cache.json
24 silly install normalizeTree
25 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
26 silly loadIdealTree Starting
27 silly install loadIdealTree
28 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
29 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
30 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
31 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
32 silly install loadShrinkwrap
33 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
34 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
35 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
36 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
37 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
38 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
39 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
40 silly install printInstalled
41 verbose stack Error: Unsupported
41 verbose stack     at checkPlatform (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/index.js:46:14)
41 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
41 verbose stack     at LOOP (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
41 verbose stack     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:18:7
41 verbose stack     at checkEngine (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/index.js:25:10)
41 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
41 verbose stack     at LOOP (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
41 verbose stack     at chain (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
41 verbose stack     at module.exports.isInstallable (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:26:3)
41 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
42 verbose pkgid xpc-connection@0.1.4
43 verbose cwd /usr/src/noble/noble
44 error Linux 4.4.0-36-generic
45 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "xpc-connection"
46 error node v4.2.6
47 error npm  v3.5.2
48 error code EBADPLATFORM
49 error notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: xpc-connection@0.1.4
50 error notsup Valid OS:    darwin
50 error notsup Valid Arch:  any
50 error notsup Actual OS:   linux
50 error notsup Actual Arch: x64
51 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**WINDOWS:**

[image: windows screen]

windows log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\Programming\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Wasyl\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'xpc-connection' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.7
3 info using node@v4.5.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData xpc-connection@~0.1.4
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData xpc-connection
9 silly mapToRegistry name xpc-connection
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'xpc-connection',
12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'xpc-connection',
12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'xpc-connection',
12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
13 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection
14 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection
15 verbose request no auth needed
16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 06:37:53
17 verbose request id b60fe4107262e778
18 verbose etag "D7L5PUPWDQU3I72FED6TBUILY"
19 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection
20 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection
21 verbose headers { date: 'Mon, 12 Sep 2016 06:37:53 GMT',
21 verbose headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
21 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
21 verbose headers   etag: '"D7L5PUPWDQU3I72FED6TBUILY"',
21 verbose headers   age: '127',
21 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
21 verbose headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-bma7025-BMA',
21 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
21 verbose headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
21 verbose headers   'x-timer': 'S1473662273.112090,VS0,VE0',
21 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
22 silly get cb [ 304,
22 silly get   { date: 'Mon, 12 Sep 2016 06:37:53 GMT',
22 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
22 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
22 silly get     etag: '"D7L5PUPWDQU3I72FED6TBUILY"',
22 silly get     age: '127',
22 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
22 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-bma7025-BMA',
22 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
22 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
22 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1473662273.112090,VS0,VE0',
22 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding' } ]
23 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection from cache
24 verbose get saving xpc-connection to C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\xpc-connection\.cache.json
25 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
26 silly install normalizeTree
27 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
28 silly loadIdealTree Starting
29 silly install loadIdealTree
30 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
31 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
32 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
33 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
34 silly install loadShrinkwrap
35 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
36 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
37 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
38 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
39 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
40 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
41 silly install printInstalled
42 verbose stack Error: Unsupported platform for xpc-connection@0.1.4: wanted {"name":"xpc-connection","version":"0.1.4","description":"XPC Connection binding for node.js","main":"index.js","scripts":{"install":"node-gyp rebuild"},"repository":{"type":"git","url":"git+https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-xpc-connection.git"},"bugs":{"url":"https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-xpc-connection/issues"},"keywords":["XPC","XPC connection"],"author":{"name":"Sandeep Misty","email":"sandeep.mistry@gmail.com"},"license":"MIT","engines":{"node":">=0.8"},"os":["darwin"],"dependencies":{"nan":"^2.0.5"},"gypfile":true,"gitHead":"a0a259e697d12cb963fbec90f1a8e7b4253e870c","homepage":"https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-xpc-connection","_id":"xpc-connection@0.1.4","_shasum":"dcd7faa2aec6b7a6e18cc5ddad042f7a34c77156","_from":"xpc-connection@~0.1.4","_npmVersion":"1.4.21","_npmUser":{"name":"sandeepmistry","email":"sandeep.mistry@gmail.com"},"maintainers":[{"name":"sandeepmistry","email":"sandeep.mistry@gmail.com"}],"dist":{"shasum":"dcd7faa2aec6b7a6e18cc5ddad042f7a34c77156","tarball":"https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection/-/xpc-connection-0.1.4.tgz"},"directories":{},"_resolved":"https://registry.npmjs.org/xpc-connection/-/xpc-connection-0.1.4.tgz","_requested":{"raw":"xpc-connection@~0.1.4","scope":null,"escapedName":"xpc-connection","name":"xpc-connection","rawSpec":"~0.1.4","spec":">=0.1.4 <0.2.0","type":"range"},"_spec":"xpc-connection@~0.1.4","_where":"D:\\Programming\\N\\noble-master","_args":[[{"raw":"xpc-connection@~0.1.4","scope":null,"escapedName":"xpc-connection","name":"xpc-connection","rawSpec":"~0.1.4","spec":">=0.1.4 <0.2.0","type":"range"},"D:\\Programming\\N\\noble-master"]],"readme":"ERROR: No README data found!"} (current: {"os":"win32","cpu":"x64"})
42 verbose stack     at checkPlatform (C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-install-checks\index.js:45:14)
42 verbose stack     at thenWarnEngineIssues (C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\validate-args.js:41:5)
42 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
42 verbose stack     at checkEngine (C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-install-checks\index.js:24:10)
42 verbose stack     at module.exports.isInstallable (C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\validate-args.js:38:3)
42 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
42 verbose stack     at LOOP (C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:15:14)
42 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:18:7
42 verbose stack     at checkSelf (C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\validate-args.js:46:72)
42 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Wasyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
43 verbose pkgid xpc-connection@0.1.4
44 verbose cwd D:\Programming\N\noble-master
45 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
46 error argv "D:\\Programming\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Wasyl\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "xpc-connection"
47 error node v4.5.0
48 error npm  v3.10.7
49 error code EBADPLATFORM
50 error notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: xpc-connection@0.1.4
51 error notsup Valid OS:    darwin
51 error notsup Valid Arch:  any
51 error notsup Actual OS:   win32
51 error notsup Actual Arch: x64
52 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Хм, Вы пытаетесь установить какой-то редкий самописный пакет (14 звезд на гитхабе) вероятно на не предназначенную для этого os. Не логичнее ли  завести issue на гитхабе? Кто ответит лучше автора, он судя по всему в issues поглядывает

Comment: В инструкциях по установке указано, что нужно прописать пути. Вы это сделали?

Comment: Так в ошибке написано: `Valid OS: darwin`

Comment: Скорее всего тут надо не `npm install ...`, а `git clone ...` и компилировать. В репозитории проекта лежат исходники *.cpp, попробуйте собрать под своей комп, ос и архитектуру

Comment: на самом деле я пытаюсь установить noble (https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) и он не устанавливается, я решил, что ошибка из-за xpc-connection